# I can't display image from file (paintComponent)

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I have problem with displaying image from file:

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        //g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
        Image picture = new ImageIcon("test.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(picture, 3, 4, this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Drawing gui1 = new Drawing();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(gui1);
    frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

It should be simple. I have file *test* in folder with class `Drawing`.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

`paintComponent` works, I know that because I displayed a square from this code.
I'm using book *Head First Java*.

Comment: are you sure that Image was created? If not, try to change path to `/test.jpg`

Comment: 1. Never upload your image from within a painting method. Upload it once, save it to a variable and then paint with the variable within paintComponent. 2. Call `setVisible(true)` only **after** adding all components to the JFrame. 3. Use resources, not files to upload the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to manage Images, is to create a folder in your project:"src/resources", and copy your images there, after you can use this code to load the image:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myImage.png");
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));
```

This should work in your IDE and also when the application is distributed in a jar file ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the relative path: `"test.png"` try an absolute path `"c:/path/to/test.png"`

Comment: It is works with the full path ("c:/path/to/test.png"). But how to handle this issue when I change path? There is possibility to display file with short path?

Comment: if the filename is fixed, you could consider creating a folder e.g. images (to contain the image file), then add the image folder the to the classpath; so, the code `Image picture = new ImageIcon("test.jpg").getImage()`; will now become `Image picture = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test.jpg")).getImage()`

Comment: No. Relative paths and resources should be used, else the program will work on one and only one computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put The path of image as this

```
File file =new File("path");
Image picture =new ImageIcon(file);
```

Also you can use .getabslotePath
Becouse in your case the image location shuld be in the same folder